# Error publishing DacPac project in Visual Studio 2019 (works in Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dacpac, visual-studio-2019

When I publish an exiting Database project (DacPac) in Visual Studio 2019 I get the following error

"sqldatabasecredential could not be imported but one or more of these objects exists in your source"

In Visual Studio 2017 I don't get this error.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520153/ssdt-error-modeling-the-target-database.html):

> The error seems to be fixed, as of version 16.1.1.